# How to generate dynamic id with mysql trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to generate student_roll_no like `20191B01;` I want to increase the last two digits of student_roll_no like `20191B02,..........20191B10,20191B11`. With the following code, I can get up to `20191B09` after that `20191B010`, but I need `20191B10`.

```
SET NEW.student_roll_no = CONCAT(
   YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 
   NEW.class_code,
   IFNULL(CONCAT('0',(substring((SELECT student_roll_no FROM students WHERE class_code = NEW.class_code ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1),-2)+1)),'01'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to solve your issue.

```
SET @roll_num = IFNULL((substring((SELECT student_roll_no FROM students WHERE class_code = NEW.class_code ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1),-2) +1),'1'),
NEW.student_roll_no = CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), NEW.class_code, 
        IF (    
           @roll_num < 10,
           CONCAT('0',@roll_num),
           @roll_num
       )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed two digit student number, use LPAD. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

otherwise this code snippet might helpful:

```
SET @number = IFNULL(
                ( substring( ( SELECT `cache`.`value` FROM `cache` ORDER BY `cache`.`value` DESC LIMIT 1 ),- 2 ) + 1 ),
                '1' 
            );

SET NEW.student_roll_no = CONCAT(
    YEAR ( CURRENT_DATE ),
    NEW.class_code,
    IF
        (
            @number < 10,
            CONCAT('0',@number),
            @number 
        ) 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @Samiul Amin Shanto